# RN - Unable to find a specification for `FlipperKit (ALL_VERSION)`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cocoapods, pod-install

my project has an error in flipper's pod install, I've tested several versions and I've run pod install --repo-update but without any effect.

My Project:

"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.5",

```
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
[!] Unable to find a specification for `FlipperKit (~> 0.54.0)`

You have either:
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

pod install --repo-update - unsuccessfully

In podfile
use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.96.0', 'Flipper-Folly' => '~> 2.6', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '~> 1.4' })
but unsuccessfully

Comment: problem solved! the problem was a package "@behavior-analytics-sdk/react-native-clear-sale-module" that was preventing the generation of pods, the solution was to remove the package from package.json, generate the pods and then return the package and run the pod install again

Comment: Please answer your question with an answer not a comment and prove it